# How to get rid transparent spaces between connecting elements?

Tags: css, cross-browser

#### Situation

I've got an element with 2 background images (handwritten SVG). Each image is representing a corner with 45 degree edge. The image has a fixed width, the element has (left & right) padding of the same width so the element's content won't overlap the corner images. The element contains a child element what will fill up the transparency with the `background-color` property, because the parent of the child can't have the property `background-color` set with these images.

---

#### Code

The structure of the elements.

```
<div class="shape">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

The styling of the elements.

```
.shape {
    background:url("http://imgh.us/left.svg") no-repeat scroll left bottom,
               url("http://imgh.us/right_1.svg") no-repeat scroll right bottom;
    background-size:10vw 10vw;
    min-height:10vw;
    padding:0 10vw;
}
.content {
    min-height:10vw;
    background-color:#0080cb;
}
```

One of the two SVG files used (this is the left one).

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0 L100 0 L100 100Z" fill="rgb(0,128,203)"/>
</svg>
```

---

#### Question

How to get rid transparent spaces between connecting elements? It doesn't seem to appear on FireFox but other browsers don't like it at all.

This is how it should look (Windows 8.1 Firefox 30):
[image: Good]

And this is what I would like to fix (Windows 8.1 Chrome 36):
[image: Wrong]

Also (off-topic) if you know anything about this problem please tell me (Windows 8.1 Opera 12.16):
[image: Wrong?]

---

#### Links

- [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fleuv/5ndg6rq9/)
- [Browser Stack](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/ef3aeee68843f1c874f4bd441d661b2bf2c9a577)

Comment: does it have to be svg? Or would a css solution be ok?

Comment: @jbutler483 well it doesn't have to, but the shifted edges (45 degree) are a bit blurry/unsharp if its done with css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using svg for your elements, you could use css borders:

```css
.wrapper {
  min-height: 10vw;
  border-left: 10vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 10vw solid transparent;
  border-top: 10vw solid #0080cb;
  position: relative;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">Hello World!</div>
</div>
```

---

In order to keep the rectangle at the top, you could use this sort of styling:

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;padding:0;
  }
.wrapper{
  height:20px;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#0080cb;
  position:relative;
  }
.text{
  position:absolute;
  width:70%;
  left:15%;
  z-index:5;
  display:inline-block;
  
  }
.wrapper:before, .wrapper:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  right:0;
  height:0;
  width:50%;
  top:20px;
  border-top:100px solid #0080cb;
  border-right:100px solid transparent;
  }

.wrapper:after{
  border-top:100px solid #0080cb;
  border-left:100px solid transparent; 
  border-right:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!</div>
</div>
```

---

## Another spin of the wheel

Here's another implementation that may be of use to you:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 180px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.blueshape {
  z-index: -3;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  right: -50px;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-top: 150px solid blue;
  padding-top: -50px;
  top: -50px;
}
.text{
  position:absolute;
  top:-100px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="blueshape">
    <div class="text">you can place text in here!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

it's using the logic of:

```
    +-------------------------------+
    |                               |<--wrapper
    |                               |
    |                               |
    |                               |
    |                               |
    +-------------------------------+

    +-------------------------------+
  *-|-------------------------------|-+ <-- borders create this part
   \|                               |/ 
    |\                             /|
    | \___________________________/ | <-- set overflow hidden to wrapper
    |                               |
    +-------------------------------+
```

**end result:**

```
    |-------------------------------|
    |                               | 
     \                             /
      \___________________________/
```

Comment: Your first snippet's `.wrapper` css looks promising, with this it will avoid "glueing the pieces together" because it all is one piece (unfortunately not on some mobile devices). Your second snippet shows how it's _statically_ (height) done with an rectangle on top. So I decided to play around with it, what resulted in one small problem. The alignment of the text is not the same on every resolution. [Check out my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fleuv/m2rux6gg/). I wonder why you used `top:-10vw;` at the first snippet instead of `margin-top:-10vw;` like I did, how compatible is it?

Comment: @Fleuv: could you please advise which mobile browser (and version) you were using? `top` is used since i've placed the element `absolutely`. And it's pretty compatable with html5/css3 devices (see http://caniuse.com/ for more info)

Comment: On most android devices at the default browser it shows a wrong `border-width` the shape is the same height as the height of the text. Or it will have small transparent spaces near all edges like in my second screenshot. I used my jsFiddle to test it. Anyway it works great on all pc's, I think that's good enough for now. I will implement this tactic into my webdesign so I can test it on bugs.

Comment: @Fleuv: Could you possibly clarify as to **exactly** what's wrong? I'm honestly not 100% sure as to which part i 'need to improve'?

Answer (score 0):

I have check the SVG files, they cannot be optimized any further as they have no stroke. So the only knob left is to [tweak the sizing of the boxes so that things overlap](http://jsfiddle.net/Fleuv/5ndg6rq9/):

```
.shape {
  background:url("http://imgh.us/left.svg") no-repeat scroll left bottom,
           url("http://imgh.us/right_1.svg") no-repeat scroll right bottom;
  background-size:10vw 10.2vw;
  min-height:10vw;
  padding:0 9.99vw;
}
```

Please check the fiddle.

Comment: This won't fix the problem, it only will make things worse. You will also get transparent spaces (only not with way to large values) AND the corners will look real ugly. [Have a look at this image](http://i.imgur.com/ccZKXL8.png). So it definitely won't look nice cross-browser and (sorry I didn't mention it in the bounty) it won't look the same on all resolutions.

Comment: Yea I confirm that it is not working in all cases, if the zoom level is changed. I could however not reproduce something as shown in the attached image.
Another Idea? Did you try to fiddle around with `background-position`?